# Move an array in the place of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am in the making of an apps script, that takes a specified range, divides it into subranges of 4 values each, and returns the array. It looks like this:

[image: Range]

Code that follows that to divide it into said subranges:

```
function sort() {
    
    const chunks = (range, size) =>
    Array.from(
        new Array(Math.ceil(range.length / size)),
        (_, i) => range.slice(i * size, i * size + size)
    );
    let range = ranges.getValues().flat();
    var array = chunks(range, 4)
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Now, what I want to do with these, is that when someone removes data from one of the subranges, the ones below will go up, so that there are no gaps between the subranges. What I mean by that, is in the case of someone clearing data from, for example, the second subrange, all the ones that are below will go up.

NOTE: It is just a function that I later use in onChange(), and the `ranges` variable was called earlier throughout the code, and it's just a named range.

So far I've got this piece of code, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        var equ = 0;
        var mult = 0;
        equ += array[i][j];
        mult += array[i+1][j];
        if (equ == 0 || "" && mult != "" && 0) {
          array[i+1].copyTo(array[i], {contentsOnly:true})
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was thinking about sort() but I have no idea of how to use it here.

Comment: What is range? String, Array? Please give example

Comment: What is the people column?

Comment: Instead of holding all of those in a one big array , maybe you can hold a list of arrays each array corresponding to a section. When you want to display them, just iterate the list of array and iterate the current array in each pass and fill the display section. When you want to update ordering of the array, it would be easier to do it on the list of array.

Comment: It's a range. The people column is just there for no larger reason.

Comment: Could you give the "ranges"  variable's definition ? as an example .. to see what are the values in it

Comment: The only thing that I can imagine that will accomplish what you are describing in an onEdit function.  What will happen to column2 when data is removed from column one.  Will it be resized to a different merge size?  Handling merged ranges in apps script can be quite difficult because only one cell actually contains the data.

Comment: So If I delete the first 16 , is this what you would want to see : https://imgur.com/a/fmZtObk  ?

Comment: Do all cells in the 4 cell “range” have to be empty to move up?

Comment: Would you be able to provide the full code for this just to check the size/length of your defined range in this spreadsheet?